# Filtering JSON data for d3.js

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I'm still new to d3, and javascript in general, so most of the practices I've seen all had to do with simple arrays, but never objects. Now, I'm trying to create a simple chart composing a week of data by using data inside a json file. First of all, the data structure looks somewhat like as follows with arbitrary values:

```
{"2013-08-21":{"orders":"10","revenue":"1000"},
{"2013-08-22":{"orders":"20","revenue":"1800"},
{"2013-08-23":{"orders":"15","revenue":"1200"},
...}
```

The problem that I'm facing now is trying to figure out how to effectively pass the dates into the xScale domain, as well as the orders or revenue into the yScale domain. If it were a CSV or TSV file, I could just use this:

```
xScale.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {return d.date;}));
yScale.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {return d.orders;}));
```

But when I tried to do the same thing with the json object, it tells me the following:

```
Uncaught TypeError: #<Object> is not a function
```

Can someone please help shed some light on this subject? I could try to create list arrays for dates, orders, and revenue, but is there any other approach?

Thanks for your time!

***EDIT***

The TypeError would occur when I try to map the data after importing the json file:

```
d3.json("report.json", function(error, json) {
    if (error) return console.warn(error);
    dataset = json;
    dataset = dataset.map(function(d){
        var date = d3.keys(d)[0];
        d[date].date = date;
        return d[date];
    });
});
```

Specifically, at this line:

```
dataset = dataset.map(function(d){ ... }) 

Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'map'
```

Comment: What's the actual code that's throwing the `TypeError`?

Comment: Hi nrabinowitz, please refer to the edited section above. Thanks!

Comment: sorry, I think I may have figured out how to reorganize the data to the format I needed. Thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You basically have two options here:
1. Munge your data into a format that's easier to deal with
2. Try to deal with your current format.

I think (1) is going to make your life easier in most cases:

```
data = data.map(function(d) {
    // get the date
    var date = d3.keys(d)[0];
    // put it into the inner object
    d[date].date = date;
    // return the inner object
    return d[date];
});
```

This gives you rows like

```
{
  "orders": "10",
  "revenue": "1000",
  "date": "2013-08-21"
}
```

which are much easier to deal with. Might also be a good idea to parse the date as you do this.

Comment: Hi nrabinowitz, thank you for the quick response! I will try to look further into your solution as I'm still having the same "Uncaught TypeError" problem, which prevents me from duplicating your answer.

Comment: to format your json there are plenty of websites to do so freely and easily

Comment: Thanks Tom! Sorry, I'm really new with all of these so I didn't know that's something existed.  I'll definitely look into it as well.

Comment: yeah i'm kinda new to the json format aswell, i found out those services a couple of days ago and tought they could be helpful for you